# Bundled Gems installing in strange location

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I'm using Subversion and Capistrano to deploy my rails app. Part of the organization is to put all of the bundled gems in a "shared" folder, so that the app doesn't have to carry them around and install them all every time I deploy.

Usually they go under `/shared/bundle/`, and then there are the different folders (gems, specifications, etc.). However, for some reason, when I run `bundle install`, they are getting installed to `/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8`.

Some extra information: When I run `bundle install`, the "success" line reads:

> Your bundle is complete! It was installed into /home/shared/bundle

No mention of the extra folders, but the only folder `bundle` contains is the `ruby` directory.

Output of `bundle config`:

```
frozen
  Set for your local app (/home/myapp/current/.bundle/config): "1"

disable_shared_gems
  Set for your local app (/home/myapp/current/.bundle/config): "1"

without
  Set for your local app (/home/myapp/current/.bundle/config): "development:test"

path
  Set for your local app (/home/myapp/current/.bundle/config): "/home/myapp/shared/bundle"
```

I don't see anything about `/ruby/1.8` anywhere. What might I be missing? Of course I can just set the bundler path to `/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8`, but I don't like to cheat.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundler "scopes" its install into this folder based on Ruby engine and version.

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/3431d6d/lib/bundler/settings.rb#L78:

```
"#{path}/#{Bundler.ruby_scope}"
```

`Bundler.ruby_scope` is defined at https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/3431d6d/lib/bundler.rb#L141-143:

```
def ruby_scope
  "#{Bundler.rubygems.ruby_engine}/#{Gem::ConfigMap[:ruby_version]}"
end
```

Comment: You're right - my directory structure is correct, I was just remembering in incorrectly from an old project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
bundle install --path=<path>
```

From the [docs](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-install.1.html).

> The location to install the gems in the bundle to. This defaults to
>   the gem home, which is the location that gem install installs gems to.
>   This means that, by default, gems installed without a --path setting
>   will show up in gem list. This setting is a remembered option.

Comment: Hmm, skipped your last line. Are you using RVM?

Comment: Running `bundle install --path=/home/myapp/shared/bundle` still installed all the gems to the `/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8` directory.